# A program that searches within a list of data and outputs whether the data exists

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to programming in general but have made some simple to moderate programs before. What I'm currently struggling to figure out is how I would create a program that would allow me to search for a specific book defined by the author, year of publication, paper title or name of journal or conference within a text file of books and output the book, output an error message saying the book doesn't exits or output an error message if the user doesn't input all the information. I'm not simply asking for someone to write the entire code for me, but rather give me an indication as to how I could start with this, explain what functions I would need to use, or to point me to a website where I could find relevant information to help with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you know anything about classes, you can create a class for a book. Read the file line by line and put those books into a "bookshelf". For starters you can use just a list of books and search linearly in the list for matching books. If you want something faster, you might want to sacrifice some memory and use several dictionaries (probably allowing for multiple keys). Here is some starting point.

```
class Book:
    def __init__(self, author, title):
        self.author = author
        self.title = title

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}: {}'.format(self.author, self.title)

    __repr__ = __str__

    def has_data(self, **kwargs):
        author_match = True
        title_match = True
        if 'author' in kwargs and kwargs['author'] != self.author:
            author_match = False
        if 'title' in kwargs and kwargs['title'] != self.title:
            title_match = False
        return (author_match and title_match)


class Bookshelf:
    def __init__(self, books=None):
        self.books = books or []

    def find_books(self, **kwargs):
        return [book for book in self.books if book.has_data(**kwargs)]


b1 = Book('Author 1', 'Title 1')
b2 = Book('Author 1', 'Title 2')
b3 = Book('Author 2', 'Title 3')

bookshelf = Bookshelf([b1, b2, b3])

print(bookshelf.find_books(author='Author 1'))
#>>> [Author 1: Title 1, Author 1: Title 2]

print(bookshelf.find_books(author='Author 1', title='Title 1'))
# >>> [Author 1: Title 1]
```